# Нужен очень резко дать стили предыдущую и следующую элементу слайдера slick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

Хочу получить эффект закруглённости поэтому нужен пока слайдер крутиться дать уже стили.
но для этого нужен быстро узнать  предыдущую и следующую очередь слайдера
вот у меня есть код но глючит он и медленно дает классы

```
    $('.sliderList2Text').on('init', function(){
    $(".sliderList2Text .slick-active").prev().removeClass('nextdiv').addClass('prevdiv');
    $(".sliderList2Text .slick-active").next().removeClass('prevdiv').addClass('nextdiv');
});

$('.sliderList2Text').slick({
  autoPlay:false,
    speed:800,
    dots:false,
    arrows: true,
    vertical: true,
    prevArrow: '',
    nextArrow: '',
     slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '-93%',
    focusOnSelect: true,
}).on('afterChange',function(){

      $(".sliderList2Text .slick-active").prev().removeClass('nextdiv').addClass('prevdiv');
    $(".sliderList2Text .slick-active").next().removeClass('prevdiv').addClass('nextdiv');
});
```

и даю стили в css

```
.nextdiv{
    transition: 0.33s !important;
    transform: perspective(900px) rotate3d(180, -45, 0, -12deg);
}
.sliderList2Text .slick-current{
    transform: perspective(900px) rotate3d(200, -45, 4, 3deg) !important;
    transition: 0.33s;
}
.prevdiv{
    transition: 0.33s;
    transform: perspective(900px) rotate3d(-180, -133, 0, -16deg) !important;
}
```

это все делаю что-бы получать вот такой эффект 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: на картинке нет эффекта закругленности)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать через centerMode

```
.slick-slide.slick-active {стили первого слайда}
.slick-slide.slick-active.slick-center {стили центрального слайда}
.slick-slide.slick-active ~ .slick-active {стили третьего слайда}
```

Comment: Благодарю. Очень помог

Comment: но когда заходит до первой слайдера он перезагружается, ждет 1 секунду и добавляет стили можем это исправить?

Comment: Действительно такой баг присутствует, и на гите по этому поводу много вопросов. Если не критично, есть пофиксеная [версия 1.8.1](https://codepen.io/PaulBarrett79/pen/WdWYaO)

Comment: Помогло, спасибо